# CSS3 3D keyframe transform can't be paused

Tags: css

I have an issue stopping a keyframe translation when an action fires in Android webkit browser (4.x).

Let's say we have this CSS (makes a red box making infinite rotation) :

```
#test
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(48px,95px,0px);
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-animation-name: mymove;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove 
{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translate3d( 48px, 95px, 0px ) rotate( 0deg ) ;}
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate3d( 48px, 95px, 0px ) rotate( 360deg ) ;}
}
```

And in HTML I have div with id "test" and with onTouchStart action trying to stop the rotation (with no luck) using JS

```
this.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused'
```

This problem is solved if change this `-webkit-transform: translate3d( 48px, 95px, 0px );`
With this `-webkit-transform: translate( 48px, 95px );`
Although, I need 3D transform. Otherwise I have many performance issues due to many objects I create.

Thanks in advance